# 'rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)

Tags: ruby

Same script different error. This might be related more to my network instead of my code. The script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -rubygems

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'authentication')

require "csv" # faster_csv (ruby 1.9)

lines = CSV.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'karaoke.csv')) # Exported an Excel file as CSV

lines.slice!(0) # remove header line

collection = StorageRoom::Collection.find('collection ID')
Song = collection.entry_class

lines.each do |row|
  karaoke = Song.new(:artist => row[0], :song => row[1], :genre => row[2], :file => StorageRoom::File.new_with_filename("#{karaoke.artist}#{karaoke.song}.mov"))

  if karaoke.save
    puts "Song saved: #{karaoke.artist}, #{karaoke.song}, #{karaoke.genre}"
  else
    puts "Song could not be saved: #{karaoke.errors.join(', ')}"
  end
end
```

And the error is:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2219:in `read_status_line'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2208:in `read_new'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1191:in `transport_request'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1177:in `request'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1170:in `block in request'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.8.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:73:in `perform'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.8.1/lib/httparty.rb:391:in `perform_request'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.8.1/lib/httparty.rb:359:in `post'
from /home/hanleyhansen/Desktop/thriventures-storage_room_gem-f7015ed/lib/storage_room/model.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in create'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__3801264735883484179__create__2558870880708463764__callbacks'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_create_callbacks'
from /home/hanleyhansen/Desktop/thriventures-storage_room_gem-f7015ed/lib/storage_room/model.rb:68:in `block in create'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__3801264735883484179__save__2558870880708463764__callbacks'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
from /home/hanleyhansen/Desktop/thriventures-storage_room_gem-f7015ed/lib/storage_room/model.rb:67:in `create'
from /home/hanleyhansen/Desktop/thriventures-storage_room_gem-f7015ed/lib/storage_room/model.rb:61:in `save'
from import_csv.rb:17:in `block in <main>'
from import_csv.rb:14:in `each'
from import_csv.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

I'm interested in learning why this error occurred as well as the solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found this while perusing the web. Hopes it helps somebody! [Setting a longer timeout](http://userprimary.net/posts/2008/04/13/setting-a-longer-timeout-for-nethttp-requests-in-ruby/)

Here is how you can adjust the timeout in the Net::HTTP API:

```
require 'net/http' 

http = Net::HTTP.new(@host, @port)
http.read_timeout = 500
```

Comment: Do you have some concrete examples of when this might be advisable to do to help us newbies understand? I would assume this often may be a bandaid to something that may have a solution upstream, right?