# Timeout::Error for selenium while loading heavy page

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm facing a Timeout::Error issue while loading heavy web page. I observed that even if I added an implicit wait call `@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 300`, a timeout error is thrown before 300 seconds - it's thrown in around 60-70 seconds.

Error thrown is -

```
Timeout::Error
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1286:in `block in request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in `response_for'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:38:in `request'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `get'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:14:in `to'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:108:in `get'
backlot.rb:17:in `test_backlot'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:949:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:17:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:787:in `block in _run_suite'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:780:in `map'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:780:in `_run_suite'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:565:in `block in _run_suites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:563:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:563:in `_run_suites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:746:in `_run_anything'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:909:in `run_tests'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:896:in `block in _run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:895:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:895:in `_run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325:in `block in autorun'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using gem fakeweb
FakeWeb is a helper for faking web requests in Ruby. It works at a global level, without modifying code or writing extensive stubs.
In GEMFILE write
gem 'fakeweb', :require => false 
require 'fakeweb'
use above statement in your file 

Hope this would work..

Comment: Thanks it worked!!! But I just made changes in Gemfile - gem 'fakeweb', :require => false & I didn't add - require 'fakeweb' in my file. Still it worked.

Comment: Accepted. I'm new to stack overflow & was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the original issue isn't with Selenium and your question is answered here:

['rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011387/rescue-in-rbuf-fill-timeouterror-timeouterror)