# Post request via Net::HTTP doesn't get a response and times out

Tags: ruby, http, post

I want to use the Microsoft Translate API and I am already stuck obtaining the access token.

This is how my code looks like:

```
authUri = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/"
paramHash = {
  "client_id" => "test",
  "client_secret" => "*****",
  "scope" => "http://api.microsofttranslator.com",
  "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
}

postData = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(authUri), paramHash)
puts postData.body
```

But this won't terminate and after a while I get a Timeout Error:

```
`rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
```

I already tried the [a Rest-Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem and curl. Both worked perfectly fine, but I don't like incorporating another gem for such a simple task.

When I send the post request to localhost and listen with netcat I see the exact same requests (except for User-Agent, but even changing that didn't solve the problem)

Comment: read timeout? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011387/rescue-in-rbuf-fill-timeouterror-timeouterror

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the read_timeout is fine. The request doesn't take too long, so default value should be ok in this case