# Getting timeout error only on mobile on accessing pages from Rails based application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

From last few days I am getting Timeout error in my logs when ever I try to access the open pages of my website from mobile device(the pages never open actually), where as it opens without any issue on desktop.

```
Timeout::Error
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
```

My main concern is why is it only happening on mobile devices and not on Desktop and it is only happening on Chrome's mobile browser. I have tested it on multiple phone's and on different browsers but it doesn't open on Chrome alone.

Comment: seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011387/rescue-in-rbuf-fill-timeouterror-timeouterror

Comment: I saw that answer, but can you please tell me where that code should be added, plus this is only happening on mobile devices on pages which do not require any login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error after a long time. I had a gem for determining user's location and showing location specific content, that gem allowed only 25k free requests and after that if anyone tried to view the page it would result in timeout error.